# Windows command script failing to recognize CD parameter for Java program

Tags: java, command-line, cmd, cd

I'm trying to run a Java program from a script called converter.cmd but something is wrong.

```
    P:\LatitudeConsulting\LatConConverter-1.8.2>dir
 Volume in drive P has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 1074-4BBE

 Directory of P:\LatitudeConsulting\LatConConverter-1.8.2

08/25/2011  10:32 AM    <DIR>          .
08/25/2011  10:32 AM    <DIR>          ..
05/11/2011  09:29 PM             2,349 convert.xsd
02/19/2008  09:28 PM               100 Converter.cmd
05/11/2011  09:29 PM           104,697 Converter.jar
05/11/2011  09:29 PM            74,082 Converter.jar.old
05/19/2011  01:02 PM             1,432 Converter.properties
05/19/2011  04:37 PM             1,432 Converter.properties.modifiedJJA.txt
08/24/2011  04:54 PM               292 FieldList.txt
08/25/2011  10:31 AM    <DIR>          jre.1.6.0
05/11/2011  09:30 PM             1,747 MimeTypes.properties
```

Here is the content of converter.cmd:

> cd %~dp0% 
>   jre.1.6.0\bin\java -Xmx1024m -cp Converter.jar com.latcon.ExportConvert.Converter %1 %2

Here is what I get when I type converter at the above command prompt:

```
    P:\LatitudeConsulting\LatConConverter-1.8.2>converter

P:\LatitudeConsulting\LatConConverter-1.8.2>cd P:\LatitudeConsulting\LatConConverter-1.8.2\

P:\LatitudeConsulting\LatConConverter-1.8.2>jre.1.6.0\bin\java -Xmx1024m -cp Converter.jar com.latcon.ExportConvert.Conv
erter
'jre.1.6.0\bin\java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

P:\LatitudeConsulting\LatConConverter-1.8.2>
```

EDIT---------

```
    P:\>dir p:\LatitudeConsulting\LatConConverter-1.8.2\jre.1.6.0\bin\java.*
 Volume in drive P has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 1074-4BBE

 Directory of p:\LatitudeConsulting\LatConConverter-1.8.2\jre.1.6.0\bin

05/11/2011  09:29 PM           126,976 java.dll
           1 File(s)        126,976 bytes
           0 Dir(s)  16,691,785,728 bytes free

P:\>
```

Looks like no java.exe exists - only java.dll

Comment: what is the output of `dir P:\LatitudeConsulting\LatConConverter-1.8.2\jre.1.6.0\bin\java.*`?

Comment: Thanks gnat. I think you've spotted something (see my edit --- above) but not sure how to proceed here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `jre.1.6.0\bin\java.exe` - with the extension.

Comment: Added the .exe extension but it still fails (virtually the same error as before): 'jre.1.6.0\bin\java.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Somehow library got corrupted...there is no java.exe present in the required directory. Thanks for your time - I am rebuilding the whole thing now from the original .zip distribution container.

Answer (score 1):

Try just `java` or `java.exe`, your java program might not be in jre.1.6.0\bin.

If it's not in the relative path you're trying to execute it from, copy it there ( assuming that's what you want ).

Comment: Somehow library got corrupted...there is no java.exe present in the required directory. Thanks for your time - I am rebuilding the whole thing now from the original .zip distribution container.